# How to get group id of Sales Manager in Python code for custom openERP Module?

Tags: python, odoo

I got a big problem with my coding for my custom openERP module.
I added a state to Sales Order it's called "to approve".
If this state is reached, the module should look, that the user is a Sales Manager or not....
If yes, he can proceed, if not, access is denied...

So I wrote my function in python, but I need the group_id from my Sales Manager to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Odoo7 you can use

```
self.pool['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_object(cr, uid, xml_id_of_the_group, raise_if_not_found=True, context=context)
```

If you are in Odoo8 it is simpler:

```
self.env.ref(xml_id_of_the_group)
```

you can find *xml_id_of_the_group* in the xml which creates the group during module installation.

both are going to get you the record you need, then you can easily access its id.